# Copy/Pasting charts results in intermittent errors

Tags: vba, excel, charts, copy-paste

I am attempting to copy/paste multiple charts between sheets within the same excel workbook. I do this about 50-60 times each time a button is pressed and most of the time all but 1 or 2 of these charts copy over with no issue (sometimes even all of them). However, it will occasionally bring up an error (1004, Copy method of chart class failed). All the user has to do is hit debug and run again and it will work fine, so its not like I'm trying to do something excel isn't capable of.

```
With wsOrigin.ChartObjects("chartName").Chart
    ' add data and format the sheet
    'transfer to CompCarBuild as photo
    .CopyPicture
End With

' paste to the sheet and specify the destination range
ws.Paste ws.Range("A1")
' rename the plot
Set sh = ws.Shapes(ws.Shapes.Count)
sh.Name = "lineplot" & i
```

Is there a better way to copy/paste between worksheets? I don't need to have the pasted charts as pictures, but .copy doesn't work any better than .copypicture. And sometimes an error will occur on the paste line too, but that is a lot less common.

Comment: Sounds like Excel might be busy doing something when you're trying to copy the next chart. Do you have any code in your loop that would but in a delay or pause? (e.g. what @pnuts asked)

Comment: I don't have any delay/wait function currently. I placed a DoEvents call right before the .CopyPicture command but I am still experiencing the same issue. I will continue to look into that though because that makes sense.

Comment: The doevents also has to be after the paste

Comment: I inserted a DoEvents call before and after each copy or paste operation but the problem still persists. It is a very frustrating one because it will work 4 times in a row with no error, then suddenly it will reappear so it is hard to know when something actually starts working.